# Build VS 2015 project in VS 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdk

I'd like to compile the `VS C++ 2015` project in my `VS C++ 2019`(`Win 10`). I've installed *v140* platform toolset but when i set `Platform Toolset` to `Visual Studio 2015 (v140)` in `Configuration Properties->General` an try to build the solution i get:

```
1>cl : Command line warning D9035: option 'Gm' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release
1>WindowsProject2.cpp
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\windows.h(167): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'excpt.h': No such file or directory
```

In the `Target Platform Version` i have `10.0.18362.0` (the only one to select from).

**What can i do more to build the solution?**

Answer (score 0):

According to the Doc: [Microsoft C++ porting and upgrading guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/visual-cpp-porting-and-upgrading-guide?view=msvc-160)

> For projects created in Visual Studio 2010 through 2017, just open the
> project in Visual Studio 2019.

As far as I'm concerned, you could open Visual Studio 2019 c++ code in Visual Studio 2017 directly.

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'excpt.h'

The compiler generates a C1083 error when it cannot find a file. I suggest you could try to find the file first.

I see the Header file here:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include`

And then you could add the path to the search for includes files in the project properties.

Comment: @Daros911 Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us.
Your understanding and cooperation will be grateful.